# Not able to grow partition ubuntu EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to extend my partition size on EC2 from 8GB to 16GB.

`lsblk` gives

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0 89.1M  1 loop /snap/core/8268
loop1     7:1    0   18M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1480
xvda    202:0    0   16G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0    8G  0 part /
```

when i try `sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1` it gives

```
NOCHANGE: partition 1 could only be grown by -33 [fudge=2048]
```

when i try to do `sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1` i get

```
The filesystem is already 2096891 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

How do i resize it to 16GB?